# Adding items to Strings Array in xml file programmatically

Tags: java, android, listview

in **`ActivityA`** I have a `ListView` and **`onItemClickListner`** so when I click on an item I need to save that item's title to view it in **`ActivityB`**'s `ListView` I succeed getting the clicked item's title what I need is how to send it to **`ActivityB`** or add it in a **`String-Array`** inside xml file without starting **`ActivityB`**.

The `ListView` code in both activitys is the same

`ListView` Code :

---

```
class SingleRow
{
String title;
String description;

SingleRow(String title, String description)
{
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}
}
class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {


ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
Context context;

Adapter(Context c)
{
    context = c;
    list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
    Resources res = c.getResources();
    String[] titles = res.getStringArray(R.array.lwastitles);
    String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.laws);

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        list.add(new SingleRow(titles[i],descriptions[i]));
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow,viewGroup,false);
    TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView211);
    TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView112);
    title.setText(list.get(i).title);
    description.setText(list.get(i).description);
    return row;
}


}
```

---

**`OnItemClickListner`** code:

```
public class Examples extends Activity {


ListView list;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.examplesandlaws);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify what's in any .xml file in an Android application. You can send data to a new activity by adding an extra to the intent that you use to start the new activity.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String title = ((SingleRow) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)).title;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra(TITLE, title);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the above, `TITLE` is a constant `String` key, accessible to both `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`. It's value is arbitrary, since it's just used as a key at run time.

EDIT: If you want to store data from `ActivityA` so that later `ActivityB` can display it, you will need to use one of Android's persistent data mechanisms. These are described in the guide topic [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). The simplest might be to store a `Set<String>` in shared preferences. (Unfortunately, shared preferences does not have a way of storing a string array. If you need to preserve the order of the strings, you will need to use one of the other mechanisms, or else do some extra work to use shared preferences. For instance, you could encode the string array as a [`JSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) and store it as a string.)

Comment: But I don't want to start `ActivityB`. So I tried to do it with `SharedPreferences` and I couldn't put it in AcitivtyB's ListView because it's a string and ListViews required String array = String[]

Comment: @user2989698 - If you don't want to start `ActivityB`, what do you mean by "send it to `ActivityB`"?

Comment: what I wanna do is **`"My Favorites"`** activity which I mean by `ActivityB`. So I wanna pick some rows from `ActivityA`'s listView and put it in ActivityB as my favorites rows? ... I hope that explained what I want sorry for my bad english

Comment: @user2989698 - I see. It sounds like you need to store the results of what the user does in `ActivityA` so that later `ActivityB` can use the data. I edited my answer to address this scenario.